# What data structure to use for raster data when using rasterio?

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, rioxarray, geocube

I want to write a method in Python that reads a raster (GTiff) using rasterio and returns its contents. Then, some processing is done. Finally, I want to write the data to a new GeoTiff. As far as I understand, with rasterio, I use the `read()` method to store the bands in a pandas ND-array and the `source.profile` to store it's metadata. This seems rather cumbersome to me compared to vector data.

When dealing with vector data, I can use a geopandas geodataframe to store the entire contents of a shapefile or a geopackage like this:

```
everything_from_a_shapefile = geopandas.read_file(input_shapefile)
```

Is there some similar data structure for storing raster data conveniently?

```
everything_from_a_gtiff = ???
```

I am new to this so maybe I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in [rioxarray](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray).
It combines [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html) and [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) similar to how `geopandas` combines functionality from `pandas` and `fiona`.

Example of its usage are in the [docs](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/examples.html).

```py
import rioxarray
xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio("raster.tif", masked=True, chunks=True)
xds
```

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 245, x: 574)>
dask.array<shape=(1, 245, 574), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1, 245, 574)>
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1
  * y            (y) float64 4.616e+06 4.616e+06 ... 4.615e+06 4.615e+06
  * x            (x) float64 4.25e+05 4.251e+05 ... 4.268e+05 4.268e+05
    spatial_ref  int64 0
Attributes:
    transform:     (3.0, 0.0, 425047.68381405267, 0.0, -3.0, 4615780.040546387)
    scales:        (1.0,)
    offsets:       (0.0,)
    grid_mapping:  spatial_ref
```

And if you want to connect between geopandas and xarray, you can use [geocube](https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/examples.html).